# Add CSS class dynamically in code behind using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Hi i want to add CSS class dynamically in code behind.

It's easy to add, but I have little different structure.

I have one master page which has one div like this:

```
<div class="contnav_bg" id="wrapper">

//  some content


<div>
```

I want `class="contnav_bg"` to be applied only to dashboard.aspx page.

Right now it applies to all pages.

Can I have to create function for it or anything else.

Thanks

Comment: you can use jquery to add/remove classes

Comment: as @NoOne said use jquery and if you want to execute in code behind then run scriptclient

Comment: @NoOne can you post any link for help?

Comment: @neha i guess many people have given examples of that. if you are going to use that, then i can write it as answer for you to accept.

Comment: use jquery  to add class add jquery in the header of your page.then make a function which change the css of your div. or you can simply change css with out creating class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to do this server side you can do it via some jQuery which in my opinion is much cleaner. Add this to your masterpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.pathname.indexOf('dashboard.aspx') > 0)
    {
        $('#wrapper').addClass('contnav_bg');
    }
 });
</script>
```

It will look at the current url and only apply the class if it the user is on the `dashboard.aspx` page.

Alternatively, place the code directly in the `dashboard.aspx` template *only*, instead of putting it in the master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#wrapper').addClass('contnav_bg');
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery for this.

**In the markup of your Dashboard.aspx** page, add the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div#wrapper').addClass('contnav_bg');
    });
</script>
```

If you're new to jQuery, here's a "getting started" tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/getting-started/

Comment: Was about to ask the same, there is nothing wrong with this. Have a +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want only some of the pages to have that class, then don't keep it in the masterpage. If you want to set it on the server, you have to be able to access the DIV there. So you should make it a server div:

```
<div id="wrapper" runat="server"></div>
```

Note that when you do this, the *ID will be changed, so any JavaScript which uses it may break*.

Then, when you execute your server code, you can get the div and add an attribute, but ONLY in the Dashboard.aspx codebehind. You can do this on Page_Load:

```
var myDiv = this.FindControl("wrapper") as HtmlGenericControl;
myDiv.Attributes["class"] = "contnav_bg";
```